# How to add words to omni completion dictionary?

Tags: html, vim, omnicomplete

For example, if I'm in an html file and it type `<` then tab, I'll get a list of `!doctype`s that I can use. However `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` is not included, and I would like to add it. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim) repo for html5 omnicompletion.

Alternatively, you can copy `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim` to your `~/.vim/autoload` folder and edit it there. This will override it with your custom file.

```
619a620
>               \ '!DOCTYPE html>',
653,657c654,655
<           if &filetype == 'html' && exists("uppercase_tag") && uppercase_tag == 1 && item !~ 'DOCTYPE'
<               let item = toupper(item)
<           endif
<           if item =~ 'DOCTYPE'
<               let abbr = 'DOCTYPE '.matchstr(item, 'DTD \zsX\?HTML .\{-}\ze\/\/')
---
>           if item == '!DOCTYPE html>'
>               let abbr = "DOCTYPE HTML 5"
659c657,664
<               let abbr = item
---
>               if &filetype == 'html' && exists("uppercase_tag") && uppercase_tag == 1 && item !~ 'DOCTYPE'
>                   let item = toupper(item)
>               endif
>               if item =~ 'DOCTYPE'
>                   let abbr = 'DOCTYPE '.matchstr(item, 'DTD \zsX\?HTML .\{-}\ze\/\/')
>               else
>                   let abbr = item
>               endif
727a733,736
>       elseif line=~ '<!DOCTYPE html>'
>           let b:html_omni_flavor = 'html5'
>           let b:html_doctype = 1
>           break
```

Comment: Is there a way to append it to the current dictionary that omnicomplete uses?